# QGIS 2.10.1 & SQL Server 2014

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I'm struggling to load spatial data into QGIS from SQL Server 2014.  I have a table with 4 geography columns (3 are polygon layers, one is a point layer). The table has a primary key column that is a 32-bit integer. I believe the data is loaded correctly as it displays fine in the spatial results tab in SSMS query editor.  Also I am able to retrieve the data correctly with custom code I have written.

Whenever I attempt to load with QGIS (or preview with QGIS browser) I immediately receive a crash message "R6025 -pure virtual function call" and down the program goes.

I've tried to populate a geometry_columns table without any help.  FWIW I do not see the primary key column listed when attempting to add a layer.

I traced the sql being generated by qgis when I try to load the point layer and found the following to be the culprit (this is part of the select query for the layer):

```
select [geography]::STGeomFromText('POLYGON(
(-172.75210512499998572 -73.81694445636215107, 
  186.90200612499998556 -73.81694445636215107, 
  186.90200612499998556 143.2662874563621358, 
  -172.75210512499998572 143.2662874563621358, 
  -172.75210512499998572 -73.81694445636215107))',4326)
```

It appears that latitude & longitude values are somehow scrambled.  I manually queried the geography point field and found latitude ranging from 0 to 69.4 and longitude ranging from -164.4 to 178.3 which seems reasonable to me.

I'm baffled as to where QGIS came up with this bounding polygon that it is using to select the layer (complete sql statement below).

```
SELECT [id],[centroid]FROM [dbo].[table] where     [centroid].STIntersects([geography]::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-172.75210512499998572 -73.81694445636215107, 186.90200612499998556 -73.81694445636215107, 186.90200612499998556 143.2662874563621358, -172.75210512499998572 143.2662874563621358, -172.75210512499998572 -73.81694445636215107))',4326)) = 1
```

Comment: This one still isn't solved, but I did find a workaround using python.  The two lines:  `uri = "MSSQL:server={serverName};database={databaseName};tables={tableName};trusted_connection=yes"
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(uri,'{yourLayerNameHere}','ogr')` [Link for this info](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/ms%20sql%20spatial/)

Comment: I think you should add that as an answer.